# Angular 4 Return data from subscribe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I'm learning angular and practicing one some project. I have 2 services:

- Web service:
  for http post to web api
- Account service: for doing login etc

now i'm calling in component as
**Component.ts**

```
onLoginTry(loginForm: NgForm){
this.accountService.loginUser(loginForm.value.email, loginForm.value.password);  
}
```

**Account service**

```
loginUser(Email: String, Password: String){

console.log("login try: "+Email+" "+Password);
this.webService.loginUser({Email: Email, Password: Password})
.subscribe(
  data=>{
    //console.log(data);
    console.log("SUBSCRIBE");
    return data;
  }
);
console.log("LOGIN ACCOUNT SERVICE");
}
```

**Web service**

```
loginUser(user: any){
const body = JSON.stringify(user);
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('http://'+this.web_url+':'+this.web_port+'/api/User_login', body, {
  headers: headers
})
.map((data: Response) =>data.json());

 }
```

**Problem:**
I want to return data from loginUser in account service to component but when i do it returns undefined on console log

Edit: I'm getting data value in account service function but i want to send it to component.

Comment: what is the value of `data.json()`?

Comment: it is response that i will get from the server. it's sending true/false in this case.

Comment: @NoumanArshad did you try to log on console `data.json();` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting response from the server as i'm logging it in account service but i want to send it to component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get data from your server to your component, so just subscribe on it, like this :

**Component.ts**

```
onLoginTry(loginForm: NgForm) {
    this.accountService.loginUser(loginForm.value.email, loginForm.value.password).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

**AccountService.ts**

```
loginUser(Email: string, Password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.webService.loginUser({Email: Email, Password: Password});
}
```

**Web Service**

```
loginUser(user: any): Observable<any> {
  const body = JSON.stringify(user);
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post('http://'+this.web_url+':'+this.web_port+'/api/User_login', body, { headers }).map((data: Response) => data.json());
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what i was trying to do. +1

Comment: Np, have a nice day :)